# Which CI/CD system do/would space companies like SpaceX use for continuous integration in their devops practice?

Tags: continuous-integration, automation, continuous-delivery, quality-cotrol

Here is an industry specific question.

I have also seen it on Reddit "*[What is the CI/CD tool at Tesla/SpaceX?](https://www.reddit.com/r/devops/comments/e20c9p/what_is_the_cicd_tool_at_teslaspacex/)*" but there is no relevant answer so far.

I wonder **whether there are, or are recognizable in near future, industry specifics for CI/CD solutions in a space engineering company** like SpaceX, compared to other companies where mass manufacturing plays a role, for example to car (supplier) companies?

*Terms:*

- [*CI*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration)/[*CD*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_delivery) - continuous integration and delivery to support continuous improvement of software
- [*DevOps*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DevOps) - body of methods, practices and also a mindset to leverage shorter delivery cycles of software; DevOps is agnostic with regards to project methodology, programming language and operation system<sup>1</sup>.

*Topicality:*

While this is not directly about space exploration, this topic does have an impact; imagine following use cases:

- your custom metal 3D printer, or a robotic assembler gets stuck due to some software error. How long does it take to deliver the patch? What is acceptable outage time?
- you should secure accurate operation of your mission software by sufficient acceptance tests which include automated testing like [test coverage](https://www.grunge.com/174465/the-untold-truth-of-the-woman-who-took-america-to-the-moon/)<sup>2</sup>. Do you need awareness through measurable facts here, while [ECSS compliance](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/319141355_Is_100_Test_Coverage_a_Reasonable_Requirement_Lessons_Learned_from_a_Space_Software_Project) requires 100% test coverage? How much is enough/a must for human spaceflight?

*Research effort*:

My research so far using these sources of information:

- the stackshare.io site (which does not need to be the source of current, correct and complete data, still somebody has published it once)
- LinkedIn search for peoples' titles and expertise around CI/CD and DevOps
- Job sites of major companies

What I have found so far:

- [SpaceX](https://stackshare.io/spacex/spacex) does not list a CI/CD system. Ok they [look](https://boards.greenhouse.io/spacex/jobs/4301133002?gh_jid=4301133002) currently for a build/release software engineer.
- BlueOrigin lists even less on StackShare; interestingly they use CloudFlare ([DDoS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) protection). According to [this position](https://blueorigin.wd5.myworkdayjobs.com/en-US/BlueOrigin/job/Kent-WA/Software-Development-Engineer-in-Test--SDET-_R2317), they seem also to start thinking in this direction.

Following from the wording of the job descriptions and other sources, there is no (enteprise scale) CI/CD yet there, neither DevOps is a big topic yet.  But they move in this direction, so there is no simple "no" answer I think.

There is also no simple strategy like "implement your own", or "take product X" because these systems being around since about 20 years are still in their development; for example, the issue and requirements board aka *backlog* of a major open source product counts about [30000 items](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/issues)! Possibly, many of them reflect common topics, but on this scale one can expect that some will be also industries specific or related.

For sure, in the beginning there must be a well-engineered concept, a CI/CD system is after all a smart helper<sup>3</sup>.

---

**Footnotes**

<sup>1</sup> For example, CI/CD is used to [build and test Kubernetes](https://kurtmadel.com/posts/native-kubernetes-continuous-delivery/prow/)  "*with a need to execute over 10,000 CI/CD jobs per day across over 100 repositories of code*". Also, Linux community [has decided](https://www.zdnet.com/article/automated-testing-comes-to-the-linux-kernel-kernelci/) to use CI/CD for the Linux kernel.

<sup>2</sup> Quote from the linked source about [Margaret Hamilton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margaret_Hamilton_(software_engineer)): "*without that software, not to mention Hamilton's well-documented **insistence on rigorous testing**, humans would've never reached the moon safely*".

<sup>3</sup> "*.. Uber’s self-driving technology hadn’t been programmed to detect jaywalkers* [*at all*](https://siliconangle.com/2019/11/06/ntsb-report-funds-uber-car-killed-pedestrian-caused-programming-error/)"